# What is the Problem with this kind of Data for Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a Html table which consists of the Data Generated through serverside php .It consists of many rows.Each Row Contains One Button Called "Approve" . when clicked on "Approve" it goes to one php file and does its DB transcations

Here is what i have  Code for "Approve button " in php

```
$cntrl = "<input name=btn1  type=button  id=btn1  value=Approve  onClick=\"callApprove('".$row['val1']."','".$row['val2']."');\"";
```

Here is the  JS Function called when clicked on "Approve".

```
function  callApprove(val1,val2){
 var url = 'approve.php?id=<?php echo $_REQUEST['var3'];?>&param1='+val1+'&param2='+val2;
window.open(url)
}
```

Now Here my Problem is when i have the data as "ABC6252756/ A#1829533" .when i have this kind of data val2 i not being passed to approve.php
where as when we have this kind of data  "ABC07- USVDL2" it value is being passed succesfully. 
Do we have any kind of problem with the (/,#) characters . For Safe Side i have put the alert for the  val2 for  ("ABC6252756/ A#1829533") this data 
It came up succesfully . What might be the problem?

Comment: @all: I have Removed the param1 and its value1 and the Value is Being passed Correctly for param2 and val2.But the Data For Val1(ABC6252756/ A#1829533) .what is wrong with this data?Can any body Be specific in explaining wrong with this data and Handling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the hash is your problem. The [hash symbol](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#h-4.1.1), `#`, has a specific meaning in a URL and that meaning is a client-side issue only; since it is a client/browser issue, the hash and whatever comes after it won't be sent to the server. When you insert "ABC6252756/ A#1829533" into the URL, the browser will remove "#1829533" **and everything that comes after it** before sending the URL to the server.

The solution is to properly URL-encode each part of your query string. You'd use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in JavaScript or, I think, [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) in PHP.

Comment: `Urlencode` is correct. Furthermore you should sanitize the parameters so you protect against someone entering something like "javascript:..." into your form and doing something malicious.  If you are not yet familiar with XSS attacks wikipedia has a good article about it.

Comment: @Yzmir: Thanks, my PHP-fu is rather weak. I'd say that sanitizing the parameters is more of a server-side issue than a client-side one.

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing `val1` and `val2` inside `callApprove` but don't include the code where you set them.  Also, you call callApprove with arguments inside your onClick function, but the definition has no arguments (`function callApprove`) -- perhaps that's where you mean to initialize them?

Comment: and yes, there are problems with those characters.  You should use urlencode() or similar functions to make them url-safe.  In javascript, it would be escape()

Comment: @jn_pdx:sorry I have changed the Function Params

Comment: okay -- now, use `urlencode($row['val1'])` etc in your PHP, and they should be passed correctly

Comment: Didn't work how?  Post some code.  Use console statements to show what val1 and val2 are.  And show the error and resulting URL you're getting